# Wrong normals after merged two meshes

Tags: mesh, normals

I am just in mid of work, merged two meshes and one of the meshes turned out to become black. I have flipped the normals, no success, and then I recalculated them to be sure, no success again. If anybody happens to have an idea to solve this I would be glad to hear.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Can you please share a screen shot ?

Comment: Was trying to, I'll try again, hold on.

Comment: There you go. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your screen shot is not showing normals, 
Please try to select one Object and flip the normals in your required direction
select other object and flip the normals to your required directions

as you combined the Objects all ready please use the mouse hover and L key to select each object.

Take a look of the image if I understood your issue correctly

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope it will help you

Comment: The only time I've ever seen faces being so dark was when the normals where wrong way around. So I assumed this would be the same problem here. Though since flipping the normals didn't make the faces any better I have absolutely no idea what the actual problem is and how to anyhow solve it. I'll add another close up

Comment: I just also got that the rounded corners with applied bevel modifier are gone as well.. yep, I have absolutely no idea what is actually happening. xD

Answer (score 1):

[image: Helpfstuff] try clicking on the faces one and see if the normals are actaully broken or the mesh just decides to be black, if it decides to be black there's not really any problem.

Comment: "if it decides to be black" the only problem then is that your mesh appears to have artificial inteligence turned on and it can decide something else for you.

Comment: lol, watch out that it doesn't take over your computer

Answer (score 0):

As too often on this planet, the problem was sitting in front of the monitor, shame on me. So, now. After I finally **really** applied the Bevel Modifier and joined the two meshes it was no problem to flip the normals to usual and everything is fine and everybody is happy and thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Great, have a nice time :)